# Regular expression for a string with a max length that contains a required part?

Tags: regex

I'm not exactly a regex guru, so I have some difficulty finding a regular expression for the following case.

I'd like to match a string of the form `<prefix>$rolename$<suffix>` (e.g. `abc$rolename$def`) that has a maximum length of 20. Both `<prefix>` and `<suffix>` can be empty and may contain any character. The `$rolename$` part is required.

Shouldn't be difficult but I just can't figure out how to do this. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have to use a regex, as you've explained, here's an option:

```
^(?!.{21,})(.*?)\$rolename\$(.*?)$
```

This is similar to Joachim's answer, but with a negative lookahead at the beginning. That is: before the regex is matched, we check the string does not have 21 or more characters.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, thanks. I was just wondering why you have (.*?) instead of (.*) around $rolename$.

Comment: This is a non-greedy capture. I hadn't tested performances, but it should be a little better. It's supposed to stop when it finds `$rolename$`, instead of keep going until the end, failing and back-tracking.

Comment: Come to think of it, `(?!.{21})` would work just the same, and also `(?=.{1,20}$)` if you're an optimist :)

Comment: `(?=.{1,20}$)` was exactly what I was looking for, thank you! But one question, is there a reason why it's not `(?=^.{1,20}$)` - with the caret at the start so the entire expression is taken into account?

Comment: @Laila - Thanks. In my expression, I already have `^` at the beginning of the pattern, so that would be redundant.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression I'd use would be `/^([^\$]*)\$rolename\$([^\$]*)$/`, validating the total length of the string externally.

Comment: Sounds right. I'm not sure you need to escape dollars in character groups - `[^$]` might do. I'll add that you want to test the length first, before the regex. It is much cheaper.

Comment: In my case it is impossible to validate the string length externally. I'd like to validate an input field in a user interface. The input field and its validation code (regex validation) are generated. I can not change the generation of this code.

Comment: @rwwilden - I've added an option for you, but it's ugly. It's odd that you're allowed to control a regex validation, but not maximum length. This is very common for text boxes...

Answer (score -1):

why regex? think simple. depending on your language, check for length using your language's string length methods eg using Python

```
if len(mystring) <= 20:
     if "$rolename" in mystring:
         print "ok"
```

your language may have similar methods like index() to find where a substring is in a string.

Comment: I really need a regex. If the problem was this simple to solve, I wouldn't have asked :) See also my comment for the answer by Joachim Rendeiro.

Comment: then you should have stated this when you post our question.