# Match substring from beginning that must end with a certain string and has a certain maximum length

Tags: regex

Let's assume a valid string consists of some sentences and has a maximum length of 10. A sentence ends with a dot and at least one whitespace character.

`lol. omg rofl.` => `lol.`

`lol. omg. rofl.` => `lol. omg.`

`lol.` => `lol.`

`lol omg rofl.` => no match

Any ideas?

Comment: "lol." => "lol." There is **no space** after the dot. Why does this match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^.{,8}\. /
```

Explanation:

- `^` matches start of string
- `.{,8}` matches up to 8 chars (10 - specified 2 chars)
- `\.` matches literal dot and a space

**Edit:** Oh, I missed the sentence contains at least 1 space. Hmm, let me think …

By looking at https://stackoverflow.com/a/1839379/498634 I think the following might work:

```
/^(?!.{11,}).* .*\. /
```

- `^` start of string
- `(?!.{11,})` negative look-ahead for exclude strings longer than 10
- `.* .*` any sequence with at least one space
- `\.` literal dot and space

Comment: A real sentence contains spaces but I do not have to check for this. I refined your first version and it works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about this? (Assuming your regex engine does support look aheads)

```
^.{0,9}\.(?= |$)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vd83)

Matches 0 to 0 characters from the start of the string with a `.` as last character and requires a space or the end of the row/string to follow the dot.

I assumed the space after the dot does not count into the sentence length.

The `(?= |$)` is a positive lookahead, it ensures that a space or the end of the row/string is following, but does not match it.

Comment: Is a good approach to the ending space but you missed checking for the space in the sentence itself as I did first. I'll merge this into mine (with source statement) and upvote yours if this is this matches Leif's needs (unclear ATM).

Comment: @halo I don't see this requirement in the question. otherwise `lol. => lol.` should not match, but is required to.